# Use a string to specify filepath in C++ (store files in a folder)

Tags: c++, directory, fopen, filepath

I am generating hundreds of output files and would like to store them in a folder called OUT in the working directory rather than the working directory itself. Each file is name according to the current iteration. (out1.txt, out2.txt...etc). I have been looking at the documentation for quite a while and trying different things but not having success.  Here is the code. (it is within a loop where k is the iteration number.

```
char outname[50];
char filepath[30];
char iter_str[10];
sprintf(iter_str,"%d",k)
strcpy(outname,"out");
strcat(outname,iter_str);
strcat(outname,".txt");
strcpy(filepath,"..\\OUT\\");
strcat(filepath,outname);
file = fopen(filepath,"w");
```

Instead of going into the "OUT" folder, it goes into the working directory and names it like this:

```
..\OUT\out1.txt
..\OUT\out2.txt
..\OUT\out3.txt
etc
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

I have now realized that on unix I should have "/" instead of "\". I have done this and have gotten a seg fault. Also a seg fault when using "//".

Comment: This is using Windows, correct?

Comment: If you are using C++, I *strongly* suggest using C++-style strings and perhaps the Boost libraries for handling directories and filenames.  The C-style code you have above is much harder to read and more error-prone.

Comment: What operating system is this? Are you sure the directory separator is \? Unless you're on Windows or DOS, it probably isn't!

Comment: Is this being run on some sort of Unix?

Comment: @templatetypedef I agree on the c++ string issue (as well as c++ `fstream`s). However, boost seems like a bit of overkill for something like this. It is much more useful for enumerating directories or walking the file tree.

Comment: To solve my immediate problem @pmjordan I believe the problem is indeed the separator. However when I change "/" or "//" I get a segmentation fault. I will now research that and if you know what that occurred I would welcome the advice.

Comment: Thank you all for your fast comments. I'm an idiot for not including the operating system & other such details. I am in fact running on unix (OS X). I am new to C++ and C and am ignorant to many of the differences btwn the two. (I inherited this program from a prof who is used to C but has begun to use C++.) @baruch In the long term I will look into using C++ style strings and to realize the differences btwn C and C++. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Boost Filesystem Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html), then you dont have to worry about whether you have to use `\` or `/` while combing subpaths. You can use operator `/` and `/=` to combine subpaths.

```
using boost::filesystem::path;

path pathname("out");
pathname /= "abc"; //combine
pathname /= "xyz"; //combine
pathname /= "file.txt";   //combine
```

If it is Windows, then `pathname` would become `out\abc\xyz\file.txt`.

If it is Linux, then `pathname` would become `out/abc/xyz/file.txt`.

Comment: Boost seems like a bit of overkill for something like this. It is much more useful for enumerating directories or walking the file tree.

Comment: @baruch: I wrote... *If you use...*. Also, boost is not about only Filesystem. It has many libraries which are also useful. So if you *start* using boost, it can help you in many ways, and can solve variety of problems easily.

Comment: Thank you @Nawaz I will begin learning about the boost library, it seems very helpful.

Comment: My problem has been solved by using the forward slash and by stating the entire filepath beginning with the root.  Thank you for all the information!

Answer (score 1):

Use a single forward slash (`/`) instead of the escaped backslash (`\\`). This should work on all operating systems (including Windows from XP onwards)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use std::stringstream instead of strcpy() and sprintf();

```
std::stringstream l_strStream{};
#if defined(_WIN32)
    l_strStream << outName << "\\" << iter_str << ".txt";//for filename with path
#elif defined(__linux__)
    l_strStream << outName << "/" << iter_str << ".txt";//for filename with path
#endif // try this , no need to use other libs
```